# Selected checkboxes in datagrid C# WPF get copied in other checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this problem with my C# WPF app:
I have the checkboxes on every row but when I select (random) one or more checkboxes I noticed that other checkboxes on other rows (when I scroll to see the other rows) are selected, too. It's like there would be a function or something that checks automatically other checkbox different of those selected by me.
There is no C# code for the checkboxes (just the definitions of the functions for Checked, Unchecked). I use a query and ItemSource to fill the Datagrid.

So, is there a way to avoid the automatic selection of other checkboxes ?
Thankx

My XAML code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colonnaChiusoF" Header="Cf" Width="26">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=sc1, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="checkedF" Unchecked="uncheckedF" Margin="0"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Actually it happens with other objects, too. For example, in this code the buttons and checkboxes are selected automatically random if I select/deselect some of them:

```
<ListView Name="listaView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}" Height="200" Width="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Idprev" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=idPrev}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="DataPrev" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=dataPrev}" />
                <!--<GridViewColumn Header="Test3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Test3}" /> -->

                <GridViewColumn Header="Chiudi">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Button">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="True">Button Text</ToggleButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The C# code:

```
 DbDataAdapter da = daoObject.list_3(0, 0, arrayFilter);
 DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(dataset);
 listaView.DataContext = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: what sc1 in your case , which you have specified in binding

Comment: Please show us what sc1 is and what happens in the Checked and Unchecked-Methods

Comment: private void uncheckedF(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

 private void checkedF(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         }

Comment: sc1 is a field from db...it can be 0 or 1. I don't use MVVM but just DataTable and DataSets. However, it is strange to me to see the checkboxes checked by themeselves (about every 9-10 record there is a checkbox selected by itself after I check  the one on the first record)

Comment: it seems a problem of datagrid refresh but  I don't find a parameter or a setting that is implied.

Comment: Maybe this can be useful....there are similar problem here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1270947/Csharp-WPF-strange-checkbox-behaviour-in-datagrid or here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d3e07d00-1d7a-48c6-8690-bcf7f3d00033/grid-scrolling-looses-row-check-box-settings?forum=silverlightarchieve

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem should be the virtualization. If I UNCHECK "Enable row virtualization" it seems the checkboxes remain as I select them so there is no random automatically check-uncheck.
The problem now is that the records are loaded slower than with the virtualization enabled.